# Refining homotopy commutative maps of spectra to maps of E_{\infty}-ring spectra

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory

In Adams' blue book (page 54) we have a map in the homotopy category of ring spectra $f: MU \rightarrow K$ where $K$ is complex $K$-theory such that $g_*x^{MU} = (u^K)^{-1}x^K$ where $x^E$ denote complex orientation of a ring spectrum $E$. My question is - does this refine to a map of $E_{\infty}$-ring spectra (or a map of commutative ring spectra in one of these modern categories of spectra)?

In general, are maps $MU \rightarrow E$ induced by complex orientation on $E$ maps of $E_{\infty}$ ring specta?

References/proofs would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~mando/papers/koandtmf.pdf

Comment: The map $MU \to BP$ is a complex orientation, but it's known that it can't be $E$-almost anything.  (It's a big open problem whether $BP$ admits an $E_\infty$-structure at all, but even if this exists it won't be compatible with its complex orientation.)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on this, but this type of question is considered by Chadwick and Mandell in http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.3336, although they give conditions on when the map is $E_2$. This suggests that in general the problem is difficult!